# Uploading a file to server using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to my server and after that I will be saving the path in my database but the file upload isn't working, It doesn't make an exception but when I check my folder I don't see any files uploaded
 here is my code:

```
private void bBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long size = -1;
        string path = "";
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"; 
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {

            openFileDialog1.Title = "Attach speech assessment document";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Doc Files|*.doc|Docx File|*.docx|PDF doc|*.pdf";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            labelFileName.Text = path + "/" + fileName;


        }
        Console.WriteLine(path); // <-- Shows file path in debugging mode.

        Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use.
    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            Uri addy = new Uri(@"http://url/public_html/assessment" + fileName);

            client.Credentials = nc;
            byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(addy, labelFileName.Text);
            MessageBox.Show(arrReturn.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message);
        }
```

Comment: I noticed one possible error in your code; in the Uri addy, you specified what looks like a directory called "assessment" without adding a "/" after it. Did you check the parent directory to see if the file was in "http://url/public_html/assessment"?

Comment: @WilliamCallahan I added the missing slash and checked the parent directory but still there is nothing inside it, don't know what's wrong here as this is my first attempt at uploading files to a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to @William's comment, I forgot to add the slash and I also wrote http in the url instead of ftp that was the major mistake!

The code after the editing:

```
private void bBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long size = -1;
        string path = "";
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"; 
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {

        openFileDialog1.Title = "Attach speech assessment document";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Doc Files|*.doc|Docx File|*.docx|PDF doc|*.pdf";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        labelFileName.Text = path + "/" + fileName;


    }
    Console.WriteLine(path); // <-- Shows file path in debugging mode.

    Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use.
}

private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        Uri addy = new Uri(@"ftp://url/public_html/assessment/" + fileName);

        client.Credentials = nc;
        byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(addy, labelFileName.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(arrReturn.ToString());

    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message);
    }
```